# Symfony dynamic form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dynamic-forms

I'm trying to get a dynamic form but it never worked.
Basicly, what I want is that, when I select the service, id adds a new field named Chambre that is get like $selectedService->getChambres(). But it always says that the Select Service is null
Here's the code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder = new DynamicFormBuilder($builder);
        $builder
            ->add('dateDebut', DateType::class, array(
                'label'=> 'Date début : ',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
            ))
            ->add('dateFin', DateType::class, array(
                'label'=> 'Date début : ',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
            ))
            ->add('commentaire', TextType::class,array(
                'label'=> 'Commentaire : ',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
                'attr' => ['class' => "input"]
            ))
            ->add('isArrive', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label'=> 'Arrivé : ',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
                'attr' => ['disabled' => 'disabled'],
                'data' => false
            ))
            ->add('isOut', CheckboxType::class,array(
                'label' => 'Départ : ',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
                'attr' => ['disabled' => 'disabled'],
                'data' => false
            ))
            ->add('patient',EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Patient :',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
                'class' => Patient::class,
                'choice_label'=> 'nomComplet',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'select']
            ))
            ->add('service', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Service::class,
                'label' => 'Service : ',
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label servField']
            ))                                                   //the selected service
            ->add('Submit',SubmitType::class,array(
                'label' => 'Ajouter séjour',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'button is-primary']
            ))
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event):void{
                $event->getForm()->add('lit', ChoiceType::class, [
                    'choices' => $event->getData()->getService(),
                ]);
            });
    }
```

I've already tried to change PRE_SET_DATA w/ POST_SET_DATA, PRE_SUBMIT, POST_SUBMIT, ... (everything possible). I've also tried some things on these website :

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-underlying-data
- https://packagist.org/packages/symfonycasts/dynamic-forms#user-content-b-write-custom-javascript
- https://ux.symfony.com/demos/live-component/dependent-form-fields